# Raspberry Pico and DHT11 not working C/C++

Tags: microcontroller, c, temperature, c++, raspberry-pi-pico

This is my wiring [here](https://i.imgur.com/azLwfHu.jpg):
`+` is connected to 3v3, `-` to GND and `OUT` to pin28.

I'm using this example found on [raspberry-pico official examples](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/tree/master/gpio).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "hardware/gpio.h"

#ifdef PICO_DEFAULT_LED_PIN
#define LED_PIN PICO_DEFAULT_LED_PIN
#endif

const uint DHT_PIN = 28;
const uint MAX_TIMINGS = 85;

typedef struct {
    float humidity;
    float temp_celsius;
} dht_reading;

void read_from_dht(dht_reading *result);

int main() {
    stdio_init_all();
    gpio_init(DHT_PIN);
#ifdef LED_PIN
    gpio_init(LED_PIN);
    gpio_set_dir(LED_PIN, GPIO_OUT);
#endif
    while (1) {
        dht_reading reading;
        read_from_dht(&reading);
        float fahrenheit = (reading.temp_celsius * 9 / 5) + 32;
        printf("Humidity = %.1f%%, Temperature = %.1fC (%.1fF)\n",
               reading.humidity, reading.temp_celsius, fahrenheit);

        sleep_ms(2000);
    }
}

void read_from_dht(dht_reading *result) {
    int data[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    uint last = 1;
    uint j = 0;

    gpio_set_dir(DHT_PIN, GPIO_OUT);
    gpio_put(DHT_PIN, 0);
    sleep_ms(20);
    gpio_set_dir(DHT_PIN, GPIO_IN);

#ifdef LED_PIN
    gpio_put(LED_PIN, 1);
#endif
    for (uint i = 0; i < MAX_TIMINGS; i++) {
        uint count = 0;
        while (gpio_get(DHT_PIN) == last) {
            count++;
            sleep_us(1);
            if (count == 255) break;
        }
        last = gpio_get(DHT_PIN);
        if (count == 255) break;

        if ((i >= 4) && (i % 2 == 0)) {
            data[j / 8] <<= 1;
            if (count > 16) data[j / 8] |= 1;
            j++;
        }
    }
#ifdef LED_PIN
    gpio_put(LED_PIN, 0);
#endif

    if ((j >= 40) && (data[4] == ((data[0] + data[1] + data[2] + data[3]) & 0xFF))) {
        result->humidity = (float) ((data[0] << 8) + data[1]) / 10;
        if (result->humidity > 100) {
            result->humidity = data[0];
        }
        result->temp_celsius = (float) (((data[2] & 0x7F) << 8) + data[3]) / 10;
        if (result->temp_celsius > 125) {
            result->temp_celsius = data[2];
        }
        if (data[2] & 0x80) {
            result->temp_celsius = -result->temp_celsius;
        }
    } else {
        printf("Bad data\n");
    }
}
```

When I use serial debug I should get something like `Humidity = 50%, Temperature = 10C` but the only thing I'm getting is `Bad data` and `Humidity = 0%, Temperature = 0C`.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**
The sensor is working on my Arduino UNO.

I've now tried UART connection since someone told me that the USB Serial could be interrupting.
This is my wiring: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6VdD.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C51Qf.jpg), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T728b.jpg)

I've activated Serial Port and Serial Console on my Raspberry Pi Pico and did `minicom -b 115200 -o -D /dev/ttyS0` but no output is set.

Comment: You should expect: Humidity = 50.0%, Temperature = 10.0C (50.0F).
What is the exact string you get?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @HenningLarsen what I'm getting is the `Bad Data` String

Comment: @jsotola the question is what I'm doing wrong since the wiring is correct and the example is from the official github

Comment: @AndréClérigo - Welcome :-) However I see that you have posted the [same question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66614561). Such multi-posting isn't allowed, as it wastes time duplicating the effort of people on the two sites. There is hardware debugging you can do (if you have the tools), and limited software debugging (since there is just one `if()` statement that leads to the "Bad data" message). Where do you want the question to "live" - here (if you have an oscilloscope or logic analyser)? Or on Stack Overflow for s/w (if you don't)?

Comment: leave the question here, i posted first on stackoverflow and then a friend told me that eletronic stacexchange existed. I don't know how to debug the hardware but I know that the sensor is working because I just tested it on my Arduino UNO

Comment: I really could use some help, I just can't seem to know what I'm doing wrong since the wiring is correct, the example is from raspberry github and the sensor is working. If it helps I can also say that I'm doing debug by Serial USB Port

Comment: @AndréClérigo - So I assume you don't have a logic analyser or oscilloscope. That could make troubleshooting (especially remote troubleshooting, as you are asking us to do here) rather harder and less efficient. You report that the sensor works on an Arduino (please edit that new info into the question) so one possibility is that the RPi Pico examples & your Arduino code have different sensor requirements. Notice the [Rpi Pico example](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/tree/master/gpio/dht_sensor) shows the required pull-up resistor. Where is yours? I don't see it on the photo.

Comment: Yes I don't have a logic analyser nor osdcilloscope. I've edited the post now maybe there's more information there

Comment: @AndréClérigo - Thanks for adding that info. I now see a different setup than the [first photo](https://i.imgur.com/azLwfHu.jpg) and now a 10k pull-up resistor [appears to be in place](https://i.imgur.com/tDPFWsD.jpg). Shame about the lack of a scope or logic analyser, as with either of those (especially a scope) this could be debugged in just a few minutes. Hopefully someone with more time than me, will come along to help you. Sincere good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a fix!
I used this line of code instead

```
if (count >46) data[j / 8] |= 1;
```

Instead of

```
if (count > 16) data[j / 8] |= 1;
```

There is a whole github issue that talks about it [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/issues/11)

I also find out that the for this to work the sensor should be using a 4.7k Ohm resitance so since my board had an embedded resistance of 5.1k I had to had a 55k Ohm resistance in parallel to pull it down to 4.7k and now the code works!

Many thanks for those that tried to help me!

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can get "Bad Data" if from this if statement to evaluate to false:

```
if ((j >= 40) && (data[4] == ((data[0] + data[1] + data[2] + data[3]) & 0xFF)))
```

Either

```
j < 40  or (data[4] != ((data[0] + data[1] + data[2] + data[3]) & 0xFF))
```

Try print out (if you cannot step through with a debugger) what the value of these variables are, and work back from there.

Can you link to the sensor datasheet?